# How does Lazy initialized singleton that is thread safe handle multiple calls to instance while it is busy

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, metrolog

I have a singleton class that handles writing to a log file using MetroLog. I have initialized the singleton using Lazy pattern to make sure it is thread safe. Furthermore, MetroLog is apparently thread safe from what I read when making write calls. I did everything this way because I have a large project, with many classes that all need to access the logger. So, the class that wants to log can simply get the instance of the singleton and write to the log in one line of code.

I am getting a fair amount of generic "ThrowForNonSuccess" exceptions just after the MetroLog.Targets.Target line.

My question is, even though I assume I am thread safe, what happens if one class gets the instance of the logger singleton and calls to write but before it is done writing, another class tries to get the instance and calls to write? It seems to me that this could be what is generating my exceptions as it would be calling to write to the same log twice? Unless MetroLog is handling that for me behind the scenes?

Here is how I intialized my logger singleton:

```
public class PacTracLogger
{
    public static readonly  Lazy<PacTracLogger> lazy = new Lazy<PacTracLogger>(() => new PacTracLogger()); 
    public static PacTracLogger Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private PacTracLogger()
    {

        LogManagerFactory.DefaultConfiguration.AddTarget(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal,
            new StreamingFileTarget {RetainDays = RetainDays, KeepLogFilesOpenForWrite = false});
    }
}
```

And then here is the call to get and write the logger inside of the singleton as well.

```
    public void WriteLog<T>(string message, LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.Debug, Exception exception = null)
    {
        if (!Enabled)
            return;

        var logger = LogManagerFactory.DefaultLogManager.GetLogger<T>();


        if (logLevel == LogLevel.Trace && logger.IsTraceEnabled)
        {
            if(exception == null)
                logger.Trace(message);
            else
                logger.Trace(message, exception);
        }
        if (logLevel == LogLevel.Debug && logger.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            if (exception == null)
                logger.Debug(message);
            else
                logger.Debug(message, exception);
        }
        if (logLevel == LogLevel.Info && logger.IsInfoEnabled)
        {
            if (exception == null)
                logger.Info(message);

            else
                logger.Info(message, exception);

        }
        if (logLevel == LogLevel.Warn)
        {
            if (exception == null)
                logger.Warn(message);
            else
                logger.Warn(message, exception);
        }
        if (logLevel == LogLevel.Error && logger.IsErrorEnabled)
        {
            if (exception == null)
                logger.Error(message);
            else
            {
                var formattedException = FormatException(exception, message);
                logger.Error(formattedException, exception);
            }

        }
        if (logLevel == LogLevel.Fatal && logger.IsFatalEnabled)
        {
            if (exception == null)
                logger.Fatal(message);
            else
            {
                var formattedException = FormatException(exception, message);
                logger.Fatal(formattedException, exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, I can call the logger and log this way:

```
 PacTracLogger.Instance.WriteLog<Splash>(message, LogLevel.Error, ex);
```

So, to summarize my concern, what happens if two classes call to write the log one after another and the first one has not completed writing?

What is the best way to have a Log client (MetroLog in my case) that can handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `PacTracLogger` thread-safe? If yes, then you're fine

Comment: @VMAtm I guess I need to research that. I assume that I am but I am not sure. I do have other threads that need to access the logger so it will need to be thread safe. I assumed that by making it a singleton with Lazy initialization, that will make sure it is thread safe. Is there more to it than that?

Comment: By doing it with `Lazy` you only assure it to be created once _and_ in thread safe fashion. You still have to provide access to that object in thread-safe way, **if** `PacTracLogger` is **not** thread-safe. Otherwise you're ok.